# Notation $(S,*)$ or $(\mathbb S,*)$ for semigroup leading to group $(\mathbb G,*)$

Tags: number-theory, notation

In a number-theoretic context, is it best to use the notation $(S,*)$ or $(\mathbb S,*)$ for a generic semigroup leading to group $(\mathbb G,*)$ by taking equivalence classes under an equivalence relation and removal of the absorbing element?

Related: does use of $\mathbb S$ instead of $S$ informally convey that the set has two laws with distributivity, as e.g. in a ring; or some other standard meaning I was not taught?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the use of blackboard bold often signifies a certain “global uniqueness”, like there is only one set $\mathbb R$ of real numbers. If not that, there will often be at least local uniqueness (for example $\mathbb P$ if you are only considering one probability measure; though many people also use $P$ in that case).

So I wouldn’t even use $\mathbb G$ for the group unless it is an especially important and specific group. If the group does warrant the use of blackboard bold, but the semigroup is not unique in the same way, I would use $S$ for the subgroup.

That said, you can essentially do whatever you prefer: there is no law against using $\mathbb S$ for a generic object.

As for your related question, I don’t think using $\mathbb S$ conveys that it has “more laws”.